# how to combine and store these values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a reminder app which is storing things locally and I've got it to store each question separately.
What do I need to do to store all 3 parts as 1 item in local storage so it is easier to retrieve?
Also what do I need to add to be able to store multiple things without overwriting what is already stored?

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- The above form looks like this -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="six columns" style="margin-top: 20%">
            <form id="todoForm">
                <label for="ReminderInput">Reminder</label>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="ReminderInput">


                <label for="DateInput">Date</label>
                <input class="u-full-width" type="datetime-local" id="DateInput">


                <label for="InfoInput">Additional Information</label>
                <textarea class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Remember to..." id="InfoInput"></textarea>
                <button type="button" id="btn" class="button-primary">Add Reminder</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


 let reminders = [];

 const addReminders = (ev) => {
 ev.preventDefault(); 
let reminder = {
ReminderInput: document.getElementById('ReminderInput').value,
DateInput: document.getElementById('DateInput').value,
InfoInput: document.getElementById('InfoInput').value

}
localStorage.setItem('ReminderInput', JSON.stringify(reminder.ReminderInput));
localStorage.setItem('DateInput', JSON.stringify(reminder.DateInput));
localStorage.setItem('InfoInput', JSON.stringify(reminder.InfoInput));

}

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addReminders);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To store the object as one single item in local storage, you can use `JSON.stringify` to encode your object as a string, when retrieving the object later you will need to remember to use `JSON.parse` to convert the string back into an object.

In order to store multiple without overwriting anything, you would need some sort of accumulator which could also be in local storage so that you can generate a new key for each value, e.g. “reminder1”, “reminder2”, etc. just don’t forget to increment the accumulator each time a new key is stored. You can then later iterate over 1 -> current value of the accumulator to retrieve all stored objects.

Comment: So do I use localStorage.setItem('todoForm', JSON.stringify(reminder.todoForm));
Could you give an example of code of accumulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new array with all the details and store him:

```
const arr = [reminder.ReminderInput, reminder.DateInput, reminder.InfoInput]

localStorage.setItem('nameInStorage', JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Comment: and to retrieve it I can use JSON.parse for the array?

Comment: Yes, you have to use JSON.parse: JSON.parse(arr)